# I want to open web form within MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using MVC5 with attribute routing. Below is the code for default route

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index"
            },
            namespaces: new[] { "Web.Controllers" }).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

Now I have a requirement to open a .aspx page from this project to render some SSRS reports.

So I add a new folder "Report" and put a .aspx page inside this.

To open this page I just write the url on onclick function of button without using any controller.

To add route for this I used the below route in my Route.config file just above the default route.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Report", "Reports/{ref}", "~/Reports/CustomerQuotation.aspx");
```

**Now the problem is that I am able to open this page from my machine but when I publish the code and deploy this site on dev server and access this url.**

This page ask me for authentication, means username and password and If type anything then it shows me 404 request not found.

Please help me on this. I just need to open an aspx page from mvc5 application.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more clarification about question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried deleting the route and perhaps using Url.Content to generate Url to your page?